# ASP.NET MVC - How to return post request results to the View?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller class with the ActionResult of a post request.

```cs
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return View()
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    Service1Client o = new Service1Client();
    bool result = o.Test(); // returns a True boolean

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result); // True

    return View()
}
```

In my `.cshtml` file, I want to display this boolean. Or if the result from the controller class is a string, I want to display it. How do I do it? I tried `ViewBag` and it doesn't work because `ViewBag` only renders it for the first time. Please help!

```html
<p>@result</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare a model class, which should have a boo or string property depending on your requirement. then you can declare the object of that class (let's say `obj`) in your action method `Test` and then return like this `return View(obj);`

in view, you should have this on top and use its properties like `@Model.<YourPropertyName>`

```
@model <NameSpaceName>.<YouModelClassName>
```

I would recommend you to read about MVC, and How to pass data from controller to view, you will get a lot of examples.

Comment: Could you write out an example?

Comment: @Jessica any up on this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to include your data into model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    Service1Client o = new Service1Client();
    bool result = o.Test(); // returns a True boolean

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result); // True

    return View(result)
}
```

and fix the view , add @model at the top

```
@model boolean

....

<p>@Model.ToString()</p>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but it only returns the boolean after displaying the View for the first time. After performing a POST request, the result did not change in the view.

Comment: @Jessica How are you going to change it? You can not do this. You need an input control to change something but you don't have it in your code