# ASP.NET MVC - Does not redirect in HttpPost method with RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I am having issues working with the `RedirectToAction` method. After clicking on the button, it stays in the current View. After opening the PAYLOAD on my browser and checking the network, I see that it redirected with a status code of 200 and in the preview, the correct HTML after redirecting was there but it does not redirect!! I have been searching for almost a day and no one seems to be able to give the correct answer.

```cs
namespace MVC.Controllers
{
    public class TestController: Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Test(string test)
        {
            using (Stream iStream = Request.InputStream)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(iStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string requestData = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    Service1Client o = new Service1Client();

                    bool result = o.Test(requestData);  // returns true

                    if (result == true) {
                        // It showed status 302 and the html in the payload was the correct one with status code 200 but it stays on the same page 
                        return RedirectToAction("SuccessPage", "Success")
                    } else {
                        return View()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I think it is something to do with the `HttpPost` method that somehow prevents redirecting to another page. When I tried putting the `RedirectToAction` inside the View() ActionResult above, it worked:

```cs
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SuccessPage", "Success")
        }
```

but this is not what I want. I want it to redirect after performing a POST request. My POST Request works because it gave me the boolean result I want. Please help!!

Comment: Any update on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498479/6527049 ?

Comment: It did not work for me for that

Comment: Do u have a controller call SuccessController with the action Success Page. Did u set up ur apps correctly. It looks like a low level error to me.

Comment: @Jessica have you tried return Ok();

Comment: @YatFeiLeong Yes I have that controller class with that action. When I tried to use RedirectToAction on an action that does not use HttpPost, it did redirect. So I am unsure why RedirectToAction does not work with the HttpPost method.

Comment: @viveknuna are you referring to this issue? Or the one in stackoverflow.com/a/74498479/6527049?

Comment: @Jessica ideally you should not keep one question open and ask a new question. because someone has spent time trying to help you. you should first accept that answer and you cannot keep the question open like you will try later.

Comment: @viveknuna alright i have accepted that answer. so sorry!

Comment: @Jessica It's ok, I am not forcing you to accept, but just be courteous. And a small note. Accepting and upvoting are different https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-an-answer-should-automatically-upvote-it-as-well

Answer (score 0):

Well considering that it works when you tried putting the RedirectToAction inside the View() ActionResult above..
I think your SuccessPage return View() method is missing. If that doesn't make sense to you, I'll explain what it means,
Basically RedirectToAction(string actionName) works by calling the respective actionName that returns the respective View. In your case, the solution will be adding another method

```
public ActionResult SuccessPage()
{
    return View();
}
```

Right below the Test() And then try. I hope it'll work in your case.